# Struts browser and server compatibilty

Tags: struts

I'm doing some research on UI Frameworks. For a better comparement, with the other UI Frameworks, i need to know which Browser and Server Struts is compatible with and in which version. For my shame I can't find such a list.
Mabe someone of you has such a list?

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you plan to use Struts 1, then forget about it. Struts 1 is an obsolete, not maintained anymore framework. Don't use Struts 1 for a new project.

That said, Struts is a server-side framework, and generates whatever HTML you put in your JSPs. So it's compatible with any browser you want. It's up to you to generate HTML, CSS and JavaScript code that is compatible with the browsers you target.

Struts is also based on the stadard servlet API, and is thus compatible with any Java EE web container.